# MongoDB move element inside a document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I want to update all documents that match a field and move this element (and I want all properties of this element kept).

Dataset :

```
[{
    "name": "Guillaume",
    "childrens": [{
        "name": "Robert",
        "degree": "License"
    }
    ],
    "students": [
    {
        "name": "Hélène",
        "degree": "License"
    }]
},
{
    "name": "Mathilde",
    "childrens": [ {
        "name": "Lucie",
        "degree": "License"
    }],
    "students": [
    {
        "name": "Michel",
        "degree": "License"
    }]
}]
```

For example, I would like to update "childrens.degree" = Master to all childrens that match name "Robert" and move this child to "students". Expected result :

```
[{
    "name": "Guillaume",
    "childrens": [],
    "students": [
    {
        "name": "Hélène",
        "degree": "License"
    },
    {
        "name": "Robert",
        "degree": "Master"
    }]
},
{
    "name": "Mathilde",
    "childrens": [
    {
        "name": "Lucie",
        "degree": "License"
    }],
    "students": [
    {
        "name": "Michel",
        "degree": "License"
    }]
}]
```

I update all documents that match Robert, but I failed to move child Robert in students

```
db.person.updateMany(
{"childrens.name": "Robert" },
{
        $set: {
            "childrens.$[child].degree": "Master"
        }
},
{ arrayFilters: [ {"child.name": "Robert"} ] }
)
```

What I tried :

```
db.person.updateMany(
{"childrens.name": "Robert" },
{
        $set: {
            "childrens.$[child].degree": "Master",
            $push: {
                "students": "childrens.$[child]"
            }
        }
},
{ arrayFilters: [ {"child.name": "Robert"} ] }
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to be using [pipelined updates](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) for this, Now we can just filter out the children array from all of the "roberts", while using `concatArrays` to append them to the students array (while also changing their degree), like so:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
{ "childrens.name": "Robert" },
[
  {
    $set: {
      childrens: {
        $filter: {
          input: {
            $ifNull: [
              "$childrens",
              []
            ]
          },
          cond: {
            $ne: [
              "$$this.name",
              "Robert"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      students: {
        $concatArrays: [
          {
            $ifNull: [
              "$students",
              []
            ]
          },
          {
            $map: {
              input: {
                $filter: {
                  input: {
                    $ifNull: [
                      "$childrens",
                      []
                    ]
                  },
                  cond: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$this.name",
                      "Robert"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              in: {
                $mergeObjects: [
                  "$$this",
                  {
                    degree: "Master"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zkyKuphMGHS)

Answer (score 2):

```
db.person.updateMany(
{"childrens.name": "Robert"},
{
    $push: {
        "students": {"name": "Robert", "degree": "Masters"}
    },
    $pull: {
        "childrens": {"name": "Robert"}
    }
}
);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gKPd9LpfohP)

Comment: This solution fine only under some constraints: 1. there is at most 1 "Robert" in the array. and 2. there are no other object properties that needs to be preserved apart from "name" and "degree".  Overall I would recommend against making this assumptions

Comment: Thank you Noel. But as @TomSlabbaert said, I need the 2nd requirement : I have other object properties that needs to be preserved